# Is there a way to run ipopt on colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, ipopt

Is there a way to run ipopt solver on google colab ? I tried using `!pip install ipopt` but it did not work.

I receive an error `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this first

```
!apt install coinor-libipopt-dev
```

Then

```
!pip install ipopt
```